#  I did not receive Keening for completing Arniel's Endeavor

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

By reading the wiki of unique weapons I learned that I am supposed to get a special dagger called "Keening" for completing "Arniel's Endeavor." However, I completed this quest days ago and do not possess this weapon. Since at the end of the quest Arniel implies that he has to wait for something else before he completes his research is there a certain time I have to wait to obtain the dagger from him? I pick-pocketed him as well and it was not there. Is there a certain place to find it?

Comment: Are you on a PC or Console? If PC willing to use Console Commands?

Comment: On Console I'm afraid, I guess I'll be alright. Just got my enchanting to 100 so I'll just have to make a dwarven dagger with the exact same effects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the dagger on the last part of quest Arniel's Endeavor but you have to deliver it to Arniel Gane at the end of a quest. He should immediately use the dagger for some magic and he will "explode," dropping the dagger on the floor.

If he doesn't, there are some known bugs with the scene:

- Keening may **disappear** right after you complete the quest, making
  it unavailable to the player.
- There is a rare bug where after completing the quest and Arniel
  disappears, none of the quest reward items are left behind. (This
  could be because the player stood too far away from his experiment.
  He advises you to step back, but ignore him and stand beside the
  crystal. This seems to work for some.)
- Keening may fall through the floor after Arniel vanishes.

  - Xbox
    confirmed
  - PS3 confirmed: I stood in right rear corner of room – the dagger
    was on left side of the bed in the room below. I heard it hit the
    ground from just in front of the crystal.

Check these wiki articles on [Arniel's Endeavor](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arniel%27s_Endeavor) and [Keening](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Keening_%28Skyrim%29) to make sure you didn't miss anything.

Comment: Do you know of why this happens or any ways to bypass it? Where on the ground by any chance? I would have noticed...

Comment: Who gives it to him? Maybe I can find that person and pick pocket them?

Comment: added some more details,did you even get the dagger from the courrier in the first place? read the quest details in link.

Answer (score 2):

On the PS3, I've noticed Keening drops, but if you mistakenly run over it, it suddenly disappears.  You have to be observant and note where it is on the ground before you run around the room.  A couple times I heard it clink when I kicked it and it was gone, and another time I stepped on it and it just disappeared.  Look before you leap.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer to your question is that you're confused about the ending of the quest. It says it ended there, but what everyone is referring to is the final part which you have to
wait 3-4 days for before talking to Arniel again, then he'll give you this final part. Previously you could ask right away for the next part of the quest, but the final part is unmentioned, unexplained and if you don't talk to Arniel in 2 or 3 game days you wont know about it. I had the same thing happen. It ended & I got nothing. Then I realized it hadn't really ended despite the quest saying complete. It will start again when you talk after 3-4 days.

Comment: What does UR stand for?

Comment: Please use correct english instead of the internet-shortcuts to retain a high quality Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution load the auto-save slot, don't equip it prior to entering the area or talking to him. Once he vanishes it should be on the ground if you lose the auto save, well then I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the room directly beneath you. I couldn't find it anywhere even though I heard it fall to the ground when he disappeared. I saw someone had mentioned that it sometimes falls through the floor into the room under you and, sure enough, went down the stairs and there it was laying directly in the center of the bed.